# How to convert const void* to istream?

Tags: c++, sqlite, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to parse a protocol buffer file stored in a sqlite database. I don't know much about streams so I'm stuck. Here's the code I use to insert the file to sqlite:

```
//Read file into a buffer
ifstream file(FileName, ios::in | ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
streampos size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0);

char* buffer = new char[size];
file.read(buffer, size); // Later insert this buffer as blob to sqlite

//...
//relevant sqlite code
int buffer_size = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0); //size of the blob in bytes
const void* buffer = sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 1); // blob data
```

Protocol buffer function to parse is

```
ParseFromIstream(std::istream * input)
```

So the real question is probably how to convert (const void*) to  std::istream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you shouldn't convert to stream because that would be just an efficiency lost. Protobuf has a method to parse from array, so this is what you should use:

```
ProtobufObj obj;
obj.parseFromArray(static_cast<const char*>(buffer), buffer_size);
```

Comment: I'm using obj.ParseFromArray(buffer, buffer_size). No need to cast. Thanks for pointing out that function.